# Schematic and program listing of 28743?

Tags: software, trains, duplo

Looking for more info on circuit board of 28743. E.g. what is the processor used? Would like to be able to reprogram the chip. E.g. program the train to stop on the third STOP directive strip, or reverse the train direction if it immediately follows a TOOT directive strip. Ultimately I'd like to program it from Scratch or Python code, but that may be asking too much.

Answer (score 2):

If the schematic you are asking is for the [LegoDuplo, Train Push & Go Motor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28743&idColor=11#T=C&C=11)

with the circuit board that looks like:

[image]

This schematic is proprietary information that belongs to the Lego group.

This element uses a Bluetooth Low Energy radio and has an FCC ID: NPI28743

Perhaps you could create your own schematic and post it here.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll see how far I get tracing the surface mount components.

Comment: I found what I wanted at 'https://pypi.org/project/bricknil/'.  This gives me the capability to do what I want.  Thanks

Comment: @F Gruhl, That's a great find! Good job